# Passing state while reading Part Flux

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor

I have a Boot 2.x app using Webflux where I'm streaming in a flux of `Parts` using `@RequestBody Flux<Part>`.

My problem is that I need to read the first `Part`, initialize an object using the content from that `Part`, and then pass that object to be used in the second `Part`. How do I go about doing that while ensuring I read each part as it's available?

My current solution is to use `groupBy`, but doing so triggers waiting until all parts are finished, which isn't acceptable.

Here's an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
parts.scan( new Foo(), (foo, part) -> {
    if(part.name().equalsIgnoreCase("first_part"))
    {
        Jackson2JsonDecoder jackson2JsonDecoder = new Jackson2JsonDecoder();
        Mono<Metadata> metadata = jackson2JsonDecoder.decodeToMono(part.content(), ResolvableType.forClass(Metadata.class), null, null);
        // Here's my problem. How do I call foo.init(metadata) in a non-blocking way while still returning foo so it can be used by the next part?
    }
    else if(part.name().equalsIgnoreCase("second_part"))
    {
        // Use initialized foo from part 1 to push second_part's DataBuffer Flux
    }
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: could you add a code snippet to demonstrate what you have?

Comment: @BrianClozel added an attempt with reduce() that should show what I'm trying to solve

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution?